# Changing theme of fabric digit screen

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, twitter-fabric

I have integrated fabric [digits](https://docs.fabric.io/android/digits/index.html) in my app and trying to change its theme.
I try using below code but i don't see any change in theme.What am i missing or doing wrong?

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="android:digits">@style/CustomDigitsTheme</item>
    </style> 

  <style name="CustomDigitsTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light" tools:targetApi="lollipop">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="android:textColorLink">#ff398622</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">#ff398622</item>
    </style
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add theme to your authButton, if you're using it, or directly to builder, if you're creating it manually.

You can find sample code in [official docs](https://docs.fabric.io/android/digits/theming.html#set-the-theme).

For example:

```
//Example of setting theme with button
digitsAuthButton.setAuthTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Material);
```

or

```
//Example of setting theme manually with builder
new Digits.Builder().withTheme(themeId).build();`enter code here`
```

works as charm :)